# Restful web service, partial Read permission

Tags: rest, crud

I am designing a restful web service to create and read reports made from an app. When creating a report its possible to add some privacy sensitive information with it like a name, phone number, mail etc. After creating the report its made publicly visible through the same web service.

```
POST /report
{
"name":"test",
"email":"test@example.com",
"report_contents":....
}
```

returns 200 OK with:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "report_contents":....
}
```

and a method to get said report:
    GET /report/{report_id}

I have another app with which an admin can manage the reports created though the previous web service. In this application I would like to display the privacy sensitive information. It uses the following URL to get a specific report.

```
GET /report/{report_id}
```

which returns 200 OK:

```
 {
 "id":1,
 "name":"test",
 "email":"test@example.com",
 "report_contents":....
 }
```

Now there is the issue. This is the exact same url. Is it Is it possible/conventional or even a good idea to use the same web service for both calls, but have some kind of CRUD management with it where depending on the role of the user a part of the information is not displayed/blocked? Or would it be better to make a separate web service with restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's OK for different *representations* of the same resource to be returned at the same URL for different requests. That's how content negotiation works.

If you are concerned about this, I can think of two options:

One option is to include a query parameter to make the choice of views explicit, and access can be controlled for each. E.g.

- `/report/{report_id}?view=full`
- `/report/{report_id}?view=restricted`

Or you could also consider two sub-resources, one called `/report/{report_id}/full` and one called `/report/{report_id}/restricted`, and then you can return a 40x code when the user doesn't have correct permission, with a `Location` header as a hint of where they can look.

Comment: What you say makes a lot of sense. What I forgot to mentions is that I will protect the API with an API key or Oauth2. Based on the role I will return whatever they are allowed to see.

Comment: Isn't ambiguity a problem when defining a model to be returned?

Comment: Ambiguity where? A REST client must be able to deal with receiving different representations.

Answer (score 1):

If your language of choice supports it, you could return a dynamic object.

here's some pseudo code.

```
if (loggedInUser != isAdmin(user))
   return new { id: 1, contents: "..." }
else 
   return new { id: 1, name: "test", email: "test@test.com", contents: "..." }
```

Personally, I would have different areas that do different things. One area that retrieves the model for everyone. In the other it'd be like an admin area.

In the one area, you have